# Gatsby default starter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, gatsby

This error came when I created `gatsby-default-starter` site. How to solve it. What is the problem with it?

Error message:

```
‼ pngquant pre-build test failed i compiling from source × Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed at D:\gatsby-project\my-gatsby-project\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11 at runMicrotasks () at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) at async Promise.all (index 0) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! pngquant-bin@6.0.0 postinstall: node lib/install.js npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@6.0.0 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

ERROR

Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

error.js:56 makeError [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/lib/error.js:56:11

index.js:114 handlePromise [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:114:26

task_queues.js:93 processTicksAndRejections internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5

init-starter.js:135 install [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:135:7

init-starter.js:202 clone [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:202:3

init-starter.js:343 initStarter [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:343:5

create-cli.js:494 [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/create-cli.js:494:9
```

Comment: I have used gatsby-starter-default as starter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using Windows as OS. This issue is usually related to some additional dependencies that you may need. Try the following:

- Delete your project (to avoid potentially corrupted dependencies).
- Install the [`windows-build-tools`](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) by:

  ```
  npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015
  ```
- Run your starter command and develop it. For example:

  ```
  npm install -g gatsby-cli

  gatsby new gatsby-site

  cd gatsby-site

  gatsby develop
  ```
- If the issue persists try installing manually the missing dependencies by:

  ```
  npm install imagemin-pngquant@5.0.1 --save

  npm install pngquant-bin@3.1.1 --save
  ```

For further details check [Gatsby on Windows docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/gatsby-on-windows/).